# How to connect two Scala Futures

Tags: scala, future

I have two Future functions:

```
def parseIntFuture(str: String) = Future{scala.util.Try(str.toInt).toOption}
def divideFuture(a: Int, b: Int) = Future{ if (b == 0) None else Some(a / b)}
```

And now I want connect them and eventually get a `Future[Option[Int]]` type result which is the second one's return value, but if I do like this:

```
def stringDivideBy(aStr: String, bStr: String) = {
    val x = for {
        aNum <- parseIntFuture(aStr)
        bNum <- parseIntFuture(bStr)
    } yield (aNum, bNum)

    x.map(n => {
        for{
            a <- n._1
            b <- n._2
        } yield divideFuture(a, b)
    })
}
```

Actually I will get `Future[Option[Future[Option[Int]]]]` instead of `Future[Option[Int]]` only. I know it's because I'm passing one Future to the other, but I don't know what is the correct way to connect these two Futures one by one avoiding using `Await`. I halt explicitly use Await, then what would be the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is this thing called [`OptionT` monad transformer](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/optiont.html) that solves exactly this problem. With `OptionT`, your code would look somewhat like

```
import cats.data.OptionT

// ...

val x = (for {
    aNum <- OptionT(parseIntFuture(aStr))
    bNum <- OptionT(parseIntFuture(bStr))
    res <- OptionT(divideFuture(aNum, bNum))
} yield res).value
```

and return a `Future[Option[Int]]`.

---

You could avoid monad transformers at the cost of nested for-comprehensions:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def parseIntFuture(str: String) = Future{scala.util.Try(str.toInt).toOption}
def divideFuture(a: Int, b: Int) = Future{ if (b == 0) None else Some(a / b)}

def stringDivideBy(aStr: String, bStr: String): Future[Option[Int]] = {
  for {
    aOpt <- parseIntFuture(aStr)
    bOpt <- parseIntFuture(bStr)
    resOpt <- 
      (for {
        a <- aOpt
        b <- bOpt
      } yield divideFuture(a, b))
      .getOrElse(Future { None })
  } yield resOpt
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need monad transformers and other "heavy artillery" for simple stuff like this. The general rule is don't make your code more complex than it absolutely has to be.

```
 (parseIntFuture(foo) zip parseIntFuture(bar))
   .flatMap {
     case (Some(a), Some(b)) => divideFuture(a, b) 
     case _ => Future.successful(None)
   }
```

Comment: ...It also has the advantage that `zip` does not force `a` and `b` into sequential order. Nice.